# Latex (book) is printing last section number at top of Index

Tags: table-of-contents, indexing

I am typesetting a book with Sections. Using TeXShop. Using imakeidx. I'd like to have
the index in the toc without a section number. Right now everything is fine
except that instead of the heading "Index" at the top of the index I get

Section IV

Index

also in printing out the index, the header is *Index* on even-numbered pages,
and *INDEX* on odd.

Here's my main file (I left out what I believe is irrelevant. This should run
and show the first problem)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{MyStyle}{%
    \fancyhead{} %Clean headers
    \fancyhead[RO]{\slshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
    \fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark}
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter. {\slshape{##1}}}{}}
}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\let\subsection\section
\let\section\chapter
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{url} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%...
\newcommand{\vs}{\vspace{.1in}}
\newcommand{\ds}{\displaystyle}

\newcommand\mychap{%
  \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont \Huge \bfseries}{}{0pt}
{ Section \thechapter\\  ##1}%
}
\newcommand{\figc}[1]{Fig. I.~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\figca}[1]{I.~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\figcb}[1]{II.~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\figcc}[1]{III.~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\figcd}[1]{IV.~\ref{#1}}
%...
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{Introduction}}
%...
\makeatother
\makeindex[columns=2, title=Index, intoc]

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}
\frontmatter

\mainmatter

\newpage
$~$
\pagestyle{MyStyle}
\mychap

\renewcommand{\figc}[1]{Fig.\ IV.~\ref{#1}}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.\ IV.}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{figure}}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\input{Stack-Part-IV}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

and here's `Stack-Part-IV.tex`:

```
\fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont{
\mychap 
\section{Verrocchio's non-figural sculptures}

Sample text with endnote\endnote{This would be an endnote} and an index entry\index{Entry, index}.

}
\newpage  
\subsection{Picture credits  for Section IV}
\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont{

Stand-in for picture credit.
}
\theendnotes
```

Comment: `\endmatter`?12

Comment: @cfr Do you mean `\backmatter`? Where would you add it?

Answer (score 1):

To correct the first problem, you could add one more `\titleformat` before `\printindex` as you've already done with `\mychap`, e.g.:

```latex
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}{0}{0pt}{##1}
```

The second problem is because of the `\nouppercase` in your definition of page style `MyStyle`. So IMHO you would need to change this too, e.g., for `INDEX` on odd an even pages:

```latex
\fancypagestyle{MyBackStyle}{%
    \fancyhead{} %Clean headers
    \fancyhead[RO]{\slshape\rightmark}%
    \fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark}%
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}%[1]{\markboth{\thechapter. {\slshape{##1}}}{}}
}
```

All together:

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{Stack-Part-IV.tex}
\fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont{
\mychap 
\section{Verrocchio's non-figural sculptures}

Sample text with endnote\endnote{This would be an endnote} and an index entry\index{Entry, index}.

}
\newpage  
\subsection{Picture credits  for Section IV}
\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont{

Stand-in for picture credit.
}
\theendnotes
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{MyStyle}{%
    \fancyhead{} %Clean headers
    \fancyhead[RO]{\slshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}%
    \fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark}%
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter. {\slshape{##1}}}{}}%
}
\fancypagestyle{MyBackStyle}{%
    \fancyhead{} %Clean headers
    \fancyhead[RO]{\slshape\rightmark}%
    \fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark}%
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter. {\slshape{##1}}}{}}%
}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\let\subsection\section
\let\section\chapter
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{url} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%...
\newcommand{\vs}{\vspace{.1in}}
\newcommand{\ds}{\displaystyle}

\newcommand\mychap{%
  \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont \Huge \bfseries}{}{0pt}
{ Section \thechapter\\  ##1}%
}
\newcommand\backchap{%
  \titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}{0}{0pt}{##1}}
\newcommand{\figc}[1]{Fig. I.~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\figca}[1]{I.~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\figcb}[1]{II.~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\figcc}[1]{III.~\ref{#1}}
\newcommand{\figcd}[1]{IV.~\ref{#1}}
%...
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{Introduction}}
%...
\makeatother
\makeindex[columns=2, title=Index, intoc]

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}
\frontmatter

\mainmatter

\newpage
$~$
\pagestyle{MyStyle}
\mychap

\renewcommand{\figc}[1]{Fig.\ IV.~\ref{#1}}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.\ IV.}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{figure}}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\input{Stack-Part-IV}

\clearpage
\backchap
\pagestyle{MyBackStyle}
\printindex
\clearpage
one more index fake page
\clearpage
one more index fake page
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome back! I haven't seen you since a long time, what happened?

Comment: Schweinebacke: Vielen dank!